# jQuery logic issue with hiding and unhiding asp objects

Tags: jquery

I have an issue with some logic in my jQuery and was wondering if anyone could help me with it?

I have a form that uses asp objects and bootstrap for styling. The objects have fixed locations but are hidden and i'm using buttons to un-hide the wells they are associated with (and of course themselves). What I've got works perfect for wells that only have one object attached to them but for multiples its getting a bit hectic; below is what i have working:

```
        $('#btn_IncCat').click(function () {
            $('#btn_Cat').toggleClass('btn-primary btn-success'); <<button colour change on click
            $('#Search').toggleClass('well hidden well'); <<the asp object wrapped in a div
            $('#searchh5').toggleClass('hidden');

        })
```

For wells with multiple objects in them i'm struggling with the logic:

```
     $('#btn_Area').click(function () {
            $('#btn_Area').toggleClass('btn-primary btn-success');

            if (counter = 0 && $('#MobSelection').hasClass('well hidden')) { counter = 1 } else { counter = 0 };
            if (counter = 0 && $('#MobSelection').hasClass('well')) { counter = 0 } else { counter = 1 };
            if (counter = 1) { $('#MobSelection').toggleClass('well hidden well'); };

            $('#AreaCol').toggleClass('col-md-3 hidden col-md-3') ;
            if ($('#MobSelectioh5').hasClass('hidden')) { $('#MobSelectioh5').toggleClass('hidden') } else { };

        })
```

The general idea is that the user would click the required button and for the relevant asp objects to appear in the well. But the well keeps hiding or the object doesn't show or i have to click the previous button for the required object to appear object.

Its a bit frustrating I've managed to get this working with updatepanels it's just this last hurdle now.

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated!

P.S: Probably worth mentioning that the script start with:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        var counter = 0;
```

here is the HTML sample:

```
        <div id="MobSelection" class="well hidden">
            <div class="form-inline" role="form">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="IncidentMobPanel" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            Sys.Application.add_load(BindIncidentEvents);
                        </script>

                        <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-md-2 hidden" id="watchCol">
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_WatchSearch" runat="server" Text="Watch:"></asp:Label>

                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DD_WatchSearch" runat="server" DataSourceID="Watch" CssClass="btn btn-default"
                                            DataTextField="WatchDesc" DataValueField="WatchDesc" AutoPostBack="True" AppendDataBoundItems="true" EnableViewState="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DD_area_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="0">Select Watch:</asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Watch" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:constr %>"
                                            SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT  FROM ] where WatchDesc is not null"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                                    </div>

                                    div class="col-md-2 hidden" id="Pumpscol">
                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_NumberofPumpsSearch" runat="server" Text="Number of Pumps:"></asp:Label>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="dd_NumberofPumpsSearch" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" CssClass="btn btn-default">
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="0">Number of Pumps:</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="2">2-3</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="3">3-4</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="4">5-6</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="5">7-8</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="6">9+</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                          </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>


                        </div>
```

Comment: hard to tell something without seeing html structure. could you add the relevant html here?

additionally can suggest to use `console.log` to trace what is going on when you click, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console.log for more info.

Comment: I'm lost in your conditions. Looks like you can significantly simplify them by using `.addClass` and `.removeClass` methods instead of `.toggleClass`.
`.addClass` is tolerant to adding existing class, `.removeClass` is tolerant to removal of non-existing class.

Comment: Ok, so on a click check to see what class is already there and add and remove as necessary (or do nothing)?

Comment: Kind of, I usually do an `if ($('whatever').hasClass) {/* turn everyone in state 1*/ } else { /* turn everyone in state 2*/ }`. Your case seems to be a bit more complex, but I belief it can be simplified.

Comment: that might work better than what i came up with, thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I was over complicating the conditions with $.toggleClass so i've changed it to:

```
 $('#btn_Area').click(function () {
            $('#btn_Area').toggleClass('btn-primary btn-success');
            if ($('#MobSelection').hasClass('well hidden')) { $('#MobSelection').removeClass('hidden') };
            $('#AreaCol').toggleClass('col-md-3 hidden col-md-3') ;
            if ($('#MobSelectioh5').hasClass('hidden')) { $('#MobSelectioh5').removeClass('hidden') } else { };

        })
```

Thanks to @Anton Boritskiy

Comment: Just a minor additional hint: you don't need to check if element have class before removing it, so you can replace the line `if ($('#MobSelection').hasClass('well hidden')) { $('#MobSelection').removeClass('hidden') };` with just `$('#MobSelection').removeClass('hidden')`. Unless there is some logic behind, which you don't show here.

Comment: In my head, the user will be clicking the button wanting to add an asp object to the well and wanting to click it again to remove it, so im just trying to wrap my head around the logic of it at the moment